# Do I, an Indian citizen, need a transit visa for a short layover in Sydney?

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, transit-visas, syd, airasia

I am flying AirAsia from Chennai to Auckland via Sydney without changing flight. The layover will be 55 minutes in Sydney.

Do I need to a transit visa for Sydney?

Chennai - Kuala Lumpur, Kuala Lumpur - Sydney, Sydney - Auckland

I am an Indian citizen with a visit visa.

Comment: What airline is your Sydney->Auckland flight with?  Unless I'm mistaken, AirAsia do not fly that route

Answer (score 6):

> Do I, an Indian citizen, need a transit visa for a short layover in
>   Sydney?

Yes, from the official [Australian Government Department of Immigration](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia) website as an Indian national you require a transit visa. Indian nationals are not listed in those countries nationals who can transit Australia without applying for a transit visa.

You will be applying for a [Transit Visa Subclass 771](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-) and with this visa you can enter and stay in Australia for no longer then 72 hours.

Similarly there are requirements for Indian nationals if applying for a Australian transit visa from India.

Source: [Australian High Commission New Delhi](http://india.embassy.gov.au/ndli/TransitTransit.html)

**Transit Visas**

- people who wish to transit through Australia and who do not qualify
  for transit without a visa
- you fly out on the same aircraft and from the same airport at which
  you arrived
- you stay in the transit lounge and do not leave the airport.

Therefore you can apply for a transit visa to your nearest [VFS](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Australia/India/transit.html) center in India. Also there is no transit visa fee but you will have to pay service charges for VFS.

Lastly you have mentioned your flight is from kL To Sydney To Auckland, I don't know which date you are flying but AisAsia says there is route from KL to Gold coast to Auckland that means you are transiting Australia and you need a transit visa.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don’t need a transit visa if you don't leave the airport. I wasted my time and money in getting transit visa and believe me, no one bothers to look at it. There is a transit corridor at the Sydney airport and you can simply walk through it. No transit visa is required for not leaving airport for Indian passport holders. I travelled in November 2017.

Comment: @55fi6j Your edit made no sense. If you think this is incorrect advice, downvote, add a comment, or write your own answer given the right advice (optionally refering to this one as 'incorrect')

Comment: Are you sure the airline staff didn't check?